# Delete UV Keyframes via Pythonscript

Tags: python, blender, uv-mapping

I have given (used this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSTp8EXSYnk) ) object (like a cube) and a UV mesh on it. Then I set UV Keyframes for the UV mesh (which I connected to a texture) on it, to move the texture while moving the frames forwar in Blender (exactly like it's done in the video). After that it looks like in the video at minute 3:00. So I have differente UV Keyframes at differente frames e.g.  every 10 frames  Keyframe for overall 100 frames, so 10 Keyframes overall.

Now is the Problem that I want to remove all of this UV Keyframes I have set via a python script.

Doint htat by hand it would work by like that: Just go into the GraphEditor, press [A] for selectiing all UV Keyframes and then press X [X] two times to delete them all. But I cannot transform that stept into a python script at all, so I can just do it by hand.

So I am looking for a code like the one you can use to remove ShapeKeys on an object:

```
bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove()
```

Does anyone have an Idea how to do that or if there is a command for that?

Comment: Could you enhance your question based on [ask]?

Comment: I will try but problem is that the original code is implemented in an relativ complex script and (bc it is for my work) I am not really allowed to post the full code on the internet ... (see edit in original post)

Comment: Posting the _full code_ is not advisable anyway: you need to boil-down your code to the bare minimum that demonstrates your issue.